# Relative clause with an indirect object

Tags: grammar

While I was studying the relative clause with indirect object, I've studied the sentences below is grammatical.

> We gave the candy **to the girl** [Original sentence of relative clause]

> The girl to whom we gave the candy is Fred's sister.
>
> The girl who/that we gave the candy to is Fred's sister.

Is it also possible to have relative clause in the structure like below?

> We gave her the candy [ Verb + I.O + D.O]
>
> The girl who we gave the candy is Fred's sister. ***Grammatical or not?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - (1) We gave the candy to the girl [Original sentence of relative clause]

> - (2) The girl to whom we gave the candy is Fred's sister.

> - (3)  The girl who/that we gave the candy to is Fred's sister.

Sentence (1) is perfectly valid and quite natural. Sentence (2) is valid and reasonably natural, although many fluent speakers have largely dropped the use of 'whom'. Sentence (3) is valid, although "whi" is more usual than
that" for a person,

> - (4) We gave her the candy
> - (5) The girl who we gave the candy is Fred's sister

Sentence (4) is perfectly valid an natural. Sentence (5) is awkward. I thik it is technically valid, but it would be thought odd. It would, in my view, be better if "to" were used. Possible forms would be:

> - (5A) The girl we gave the candy to is Fred's sister.
> - (5B) We gave the candy to Jane, Fred's sistyer.